# Drawing on Bing Map Control

Tags: wpf, windows-7, bing-maps

I am writing an software which runs on windows 7 tablet in WPF (with Bing Maps).

I want to draw when the mouse is dragged, I wanted to use this guide: [Drawing on bing maps](http://ngjon.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/interactive-drawing-on-the-silverlight-map-control/) But I can't find the mouseTap event on the Map control. I guess it's only avaliable in the Silverlight version. How Should I trace the mouse?

Also, I need to freeze the map (because touching it right now changing the display of the map). Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Tap event in WPF. You would have to deal with the following mouse events.

- [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx)
- [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove.aspx)
- [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseup.aspx)

There are also the somewhat more specialzed events

- [MouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown.aspx)
- [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx)
- [MouseRightButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouserightbuttondown.aspx)
- [MouseRightButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouserightbuttonup.aspx)

In cases where you need to handle the event before the Bing Maps Control, you may need to use the appropriate tunneling events listed below. To prevent further event handling by the Bing Maps Control set the [RoutedEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx) flag to true.

- [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx)
- [PreviewMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousemove.aspx)
- [PreviewMouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup.aspx)
- etc with LeftButton and RightButton

Comment: I had to change the RoutedEventArgs.Handled as you said. Thank you very much!